# jQuery .height() increases height, but won't reduce height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with four menu items that looks like this:

```html
<div class="grid flex bottom-menu">
   <div class="col_3 center-block">
    <div class="col_3 center-block left-block"><a href="./views/experts.html"><h2>Learn from Experts</h2></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col_3 center-block">
    <div class="col_3 center-block left-center-block"><a href="./views/join-the-community.html"><h2>Join the Community</h2></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col_3 center-block">
    <div class="col_3 center-block right-center-block"><a href="./views/upcoming-events.html"><h2>Upcoming Events</h2></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col_3 center-block">
    <div class="col_3 center-block right-block"><a href="./views/past-events.html"><h2>Past Events</h2></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

The titles for the menu items aren't all the same length, so on smaller screens where some of the menu titles are on 2 lines and others aren't, I want the `<div>`s holding the shorter titles to grow anyway so the don't show the white space behind them. I used jQuery to do it like this:

```js
 //make main menu dynamically change height
 var originalHeight = $('.bottom-menu').prop('scrollHeight');
 $(window).resize(function () {
  var tallestMenuBlock = $('.bottom-menu').prop('scrollHeight');
  if ($(window).width <= 780) {
   $('.center-block').height(originalHeight);
  }
  if ($(window).width() > 780 && $(window).height()) {
   $('.center-block').height(tallestMenuBlock);
  } 
  if (!$(window).width() > 780 && !$(window).height()) {
   $('.center-block').height(originalHeight);
   $('.bottom-menu').height(originalHeight);
  }
   console.log(tallestMenuBlock, 'GGGG', $(window).width(), 'LLL', originalHeight);
  
 });
```

You [can view the full custom.css file here](https://github.com/mb4ms/event-site/blob/in-progress-branch/css/custom.css). Here is the relevant CSS:

```css
.bottom-menu {
   overflow: hidden;
}

.center-block  {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 width: 25%;
}

.center-block h2 {
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
}

.left-block {
 background-color: rgba(218, 59, 1, 0.6);
 width: 100%;
}

.left-block-hover {
 background-color: rgba(218, 59, 1, .8);
}
.left-center-block {
 background-color: rgba(180, 0, 158, .6);
 width: 100%;
}

.left-center-block-hover {
 background-color: rgba(180, 0, 158, .8);
}
.right-center-block {
 background-color: rgba(255, 185, 0, .6);
 width: 100%;
}

.right-center-block-hover {
 background-color: rgba(255, 185, 0, .8);
}

.right-block {
 background-color: rgba(232, 17, 35, .6);
 width: 100%;
}

.right-block-hover {
 background-color: rgba(232, 17, 35, .8);
}
```

This increases the height of the divs around the shorter titles to match the others when the screen shrinks, no problem. The issue is that when I re-increase the size of my window after I have shrunk it to where the titles move on to 2 lines, the menu divs remain at the taller height and do not reduce their height to their original height.

I've been trying to make this work for a while and I can't find what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated. If you want to see the full project you can see it on my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mb4ms/event-site/tree/in-progress-branch) The specific html file I'm working on above [can be found here](https://github.com/mb4ms/event-site/blob/in-progress-branch/test.html)

Comment: can you include your css? have you thought about using `.animate()` instead of `.height()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dwreck08 was right, I needed to use media queries, this did the trick:

```css
@media all and (min-width: 780px) and (max-width: 1360px) {
 .left-block {
  height: 140px;
 }
 .left-center-block {
  height: 140px; 
 }
 .right-center-block {
  height: 140px; 
 }
 .right-block {
  height: 140px; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your first `if` statment, you have `$(window).width` but it should be `$(window).width()` like the others.

Also, to get the height of the menu divs back to their original height, you need to capture their height and not the `.bottom-menu`'s height. Also, you should use `.height()`:

```
var originalHeight = $('.center-block').height();
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxw5941x/4/)

Or you can just change their height to auto:

```
$('.center-block').css('height', 'auto');
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxw5941x/6/)

***Additional note:***

I'm not sure what the `$(window).height()` is supposed to do since there is no condition.

Finally, I would recommend `media-queries` instead of using JS.

Comment: Thanks dwreck08 I added the CSS to my question above.

Comment: I added that by accident when tired last night instead of .width(), but I found that removing it or using .width() cause the divs to stay at 80px and never grow. Weird I know. I think it's all somehow related to making it `{overflow: hidden}` but if I don't do that then the links in the menu don't work.

Comment: `$(window).height()` returns the height of the window as an integer. so it will be evaluated `true` as long as it's larger than `0`.

Comment: dwreck08, you were right, I needed to be using media queries. Thanks!